# Featured and related products REST API Magento 2

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, product-links

Is there is a built in REST APIs for both `Featured and Related products` in Magento because I looked in the reference and couldn't find?

Comment: I'm not sure about the `Featured` products. Seem that it is a custom type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

API for the product Links: `related`, `crosssell`, `upsell`. We can try with some APIs:

```
GET    /V1/products/links/types
GET    /V1/products/links/:type/attributes
GET    /V1/products/:sku/links/:type
POST   /V1/products/:sku/links
DELETE /V1/products/:sku/links/:type/:linkedProductSku
PUT    /V1/products/:sku/links
```

Swagger and List:

- http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/
- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/rest/list.html#catalog

Comment: What about Featured?

Comment: Seem that we don't have the api for featured product. We need to buid a custom one.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh Please gives example how to get related products.

like 
http://testwebsite.com/rest/V1/products/:sku/links/:type